# R - Sorting variable based on the number of values in it

Tags: r, sorting

I welcome myself on Stackoverflow because for the first time in a few year I've not find someone who hasn't asked the same question that is on my mind (if i'm mistaking, my bad).

I'm currently using R to analyse a data base that I've build up.
It's is composed of around 75 individuals from differents studies. This means that, among other things, the data frame is incomplete (not every individual has a value for every variables) which can lead to difficulties for statistical tests.

To visualize that, I'm wondering if there is a cool, clean and quick way to sort* my variables (not the individuals) base on the number of value (or Na's) that it has? If the script can aggregate variables that have a value for roughly the same individuals it would make my week. (If there is a way to do that in LibreOffice sheet it's good for me too)

Thanks everyone

*I don't which to complete the data base using MissMDA or an equivalent now

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be very useful to have example data.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, there is. Consider the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(proband = c("John", "Mary", "Simon", "Paul"),
                 age = c(90, NA, 20, NA),
                 town = c("Las Vegas", "Paris", "Berlin", "Tokyo"),
                 knows_r = c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE))
```

Now we could use `dplyr`, `arrange` and a function called `rowSums` in combination with `is.na()` like so:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(desc(rowSums(is.na(.))))
```

This would yield

```
  proband age      town knows_r
1    Mary  NA     Paris      NA
2    Paul  NA     Tokyo   FALSE
3    John  90 Las Vegas    TRUE
4   Simon  20    Berlin   FALSE
```

You see, the record with the most `NA`s (Mary) is shown on top. You could of course change this to:

```
df %>%
  arrange(rowSums(is.na(.)))
```

Which would produce

```
  proband age      town knows_r
1    John  90 Las Vegas    TRUE
2   Simon  20    Berlin   FALSE
3    Paul  NA     Tokyo   FALSE
4    Mary  NA     Paris      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text ="
obs varx vary varz
1   1    1    1
2   NA   NA   1
3   1    NA   1
")

df[names(sort(colSums(is.na(df))))]

#   obs varz varx vary
# 1   1    1    1    1
# 2   2    1   NA   NA
# 3   3    1    1   NA
```

- `is.na(df)` creates a matrix of logical values, `TRUE` if the cell is `NA`, `FALSE` otherwise
- `colSums` sums those `TRUE` or `FALSE` values so that you get a vector with the count of `NA` values in each column (with the name of the column as the name of the vector element)
- `sort` sorts that vector from lowest to highest (low count of `NA`s to high count of `NA`s)
- `names` creates a vector of the names (which are the column names) of the sorted vector
- `df[`...`]` subsets the data frame to the columns specified in the order specified, effectively reordering the columns

so each step looks like...

```
is.na(df)
#        obs  varx  vary  varz
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

colSums(is.na(df))
# obs varx vary varz 
#   0    1    2    0 

sort(colSums(is.na(df)))
# obs varz varx vary 
#   0    0    1    2 

names(sort(colSums(is.na(df))))
# [1] "obs"  "varz" "varx" "vary"
```

Comment: it's pretty self-explanatory, but ok